# Ignore parameters when using ISQLQuery in NHibernate

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, isqlquery

I have to execute a native sql statement with NHibernate to the database.
For this, i use:

```
var query = session.CreateSQLQuery(sql);
query.ExecuteUpdate();
```

Now, the sql contains the character : in a Column-Alias (which I need on this way) and NHibernate is handling this with a parameter.
I haven't any parameter in this sql statement. Can I define somewhere, that NHibernate should not manage parameters for this ISQLQuery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to escape colon (:) character while executing native SQL queries against an Informix database using NHibernate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845130/how-to-escape-colon-character-while-executing-native-sql-queries-against-an)

Comment: I cannot use the solution of this other question because I have the colon in the alias of a column and cannot replace it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use native connection for native SQL execution:

```
var cmd = session.Connection.CreateCommand(); // session is a NHibernate session
cmd.CommandText = sql;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```